# Create a safe Menu Item Navigation class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I do have a `MenuItemNavigation` class that used to use strings and then a 'menu creator' creates the menus.

```
public class MenuItemNavigation
{
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string Controller { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
}
```

I would like make this class more "type safe" by passing the Controller Class Type and action instead of strings which cannot be renamed or safe compiled.

How can I achieve this?

I would like to ensure that Controller is really a `Controller` Type and the action was really an `IActionResult` returning function.

Comment: [T4MVC](https://github.com/T4MVC/T4MVC) (or you can just do something like `Controller = typeof(YourControllerClass).Name;`

Comment: Are you current using Swagger/Swashbuckle? There are some ways you can hook into its' ecosystem to pull out what you're looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the [nameof](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/nameof) expression. Example:

```
MenuItemNavigation navItem = new MenuItemNavigation
{
    Label = "Home",
    Controller = nameof(HomeController),
    Action = nameof(HomeController.Index)
}
```

This will save you when refactoring but it won't guarantee that HomeController really is a `Controller` and the Index method really returns an `IActionResult`.

I'm sure if you're really worried about it you could write a unit test to check their types for you, but I think you'd be more concerned about a name change in the controller or action not being reflected anywhere you're referencing them by name. The nameof expression will take care of that instance.

Comment: nameof is special. It doesn't care if members are static or not. It's even used in the MSDN doc I linked to do exactly this -- "@nameof(UserController.SignUp))"